# JS Asynchronous calls - my callback method is not working to check an image dimensions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a boolean function here called checkURL that checks if a picture has 100 x 100 pixels. If so it returns true. There is an asynchronous call within the function to check the size of the image.

```
function checkURL(url, callback) {

    var valid;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;

    img.onload = function (callback) {

        valid = callback(img.width, img.height);

    };
    console.log(valid);
    return valid;
}


function nextStep(w, h) {
    if (w == 100 && h == 100) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

var pic_valid = checkURL(a_url, nextStep);
```

I am getting the error:

> callback is not defined

within the checkURL function. I am also worrying that the variable valid within checkURL will end up being invalid.

ADDITIONAL EDIT: If I add console.log(valid); before returning valid I get undefined. Is this expected?

Comment: All the code that relies on the response needs to be in (or at least originated from) the callback. That's why there's a callback in the first place.

Comment: Your error message doesn't make sense. What browser are you using? I'd expect it to say something like *"callback is not a function"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define callback here:

```
function checkURL(url, callback) {
```

Then you redefine it here:

```
img.onload = function(callback){
```

… which masks the variable you actually give a value to.

Don't mask it:

```
img.onload = function(){
```

Comment: Thankyou. Is it expected to get 'undefined' for valid before returning it in checkURL?

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line:

```
 img.onload = function(callback){
```

to this:

```
 img.onload = function(){
```

Because you are creating a new var `callback` in the new scope, and you don't need it there.